# Django: Views: class vs function

Tags: django, django-views

I'm working on a small Django project and I noticed there are different ways to write a view.

What's the difference between a view created with a class and a view created with a function?

When should I use which one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has all the same differences that are between Procedural Programming and Object Oriented Programming. It makes sense to write functions for extremely simple views, but not beyond that. There is nothing worse than stuffing 400 lines of code into one big function called view, which becomes a nightmare to read, refactor or test.

In addition to that, Django generic views exploit Template Method design pattern and provide a lot of already written common code for generic use cases, which can often be easily extended to one's needs.

Answer (score 0):

The most important advantage of using a class based views is `inheritance`.

When working on a big projects, its highly possible to come across multiple views which have similar use, hence you can inherit a class based view to write a new more specific view which is custom to the required method, or you could just reuse the already defined view as is if it serves the purpose.

Generally the function based views are used when the class based views become too complex to implement.

If you are working on a small project you could just use function based views as it will appear to you that the class based views are little more painful to write (At least i felt like it).